# How to generate session-id in Diameter Base Protocol

Tags: diameter-protocol

As per RFC 6733 (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6733#section-8.8) session-id should be in below format:

```
  <DiameterIdentity>;<high 32 bits>;<low 32 bits>[;<optional value>]
```

DiameterIdentity can be FQDN/Realm but we  need to set some high and low 32 bits value

Can someone please suggest  how we can implement it in Java.In Optional value I am thinking to put event timestamp

Answer (score 0):

Since session-id should be unique the best thing is to use current time (for example in ms) and use the result for high/low value.

For example You can also do the high value permanent and use the time for the low value.

Answer (score 0):

import java.util.UUID;
import com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.uuid.Uuids;

UUID subscriptionId = Uuids.timeBased();